# How to insert an image in LaTeX in such a way that it doesn't affect its environment

Tags: graphics

I want to put an image in my LaTeX document, and give it a precise position in it. For example 100 pixels to the right, 50 pixels "down". And I also want that when I put this image, the rest of the text stays just as it is with out the image, and the image has to be at the bottom, with the text and hline, and everything else above it.

I have found some packages that allow to put a background image, I was using

```
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{mdframed}
```

and then `\URCornerWallPaper{size}{image.png}` to place it, which is close to where I want it, but I can't move it from there, and I have to move it.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

I was also told that I could do this with the `\put` command, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. AN small, complete document, which will show your problem, would be helpful to help you.

Comment: Are you looking to insert the picture inside a box of zero height and width? Look up some uses of `\smash`!

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(100,-50){\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{picture}
```

will make a 0-sized box at the current position and print the image offset by 100pt to the right and 50pt down.